# discord.py snipe command shows deleted messages from other guilds

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am making a snipe command. It works but then it also shows deleted messages from other guilds, anyway to fix this? Here is the code:-

```
snipe_message_content = None
snipe_message_author = None

@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    global snipe_message_content
    global snipe_message_author


    snipe_message_content = message.content
    snipe_message_author = message.author.name 
    await asyncio.sleep(60)  
    snipe_message_author = None 
    snipe_message_content = None

@client.command()
async def snipe(message):
    if snipe_message_content==None:
        
        await message.channel.send("Nothing to snipe is found here!")
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content}", color=message.author.color)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested By {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}")
        embed.set_author(name = f"Sniped the message deleted by : {snipe_message_author}")
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        return
```

Comment: You're not specifying which guild it should be sniped from.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64383524/discord-py-snipe-command) (Probably not duplicate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using dictionaries, and defining them as one in the first place:

```py
snipe_message_content = {}
snipe_message_author = {}
```

And then in `on_message_delete`, edit to use the `message.guild` entry in the dict:

```py
snipe_message_content[message.guild] = message.content
snipe_message_author[message.guild] = message.author.name 
await asyncio.sleep(60)  
snipe_message_author[message.guild] = None 
snipe_message_content[message.guild] = None
```

also edit in `snipe(message)` to use the `message.guild` entry in the dict:

```py
@client.command()
async def snipe(message):
    try:
        if snipe_message_content[message.guild]==None:
            await message.channel.send("Nothing to snipe is found here!")
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content[message.guild]}", color=message.author.color)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested By {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}")
            embed.set_author(name = f"Sniped the message deleted by : {snipe_message_author[message.guild]}")
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
            return
    except KeyError:
        await message.channel.send("Nothing to snipe is found here!")
```

Comment: It works but something is [wrong](https://imgur.com/a/KUZaTIa)

Comment: Why is this happening Any Idea?

Comment: Yeah I forgot to add `[message.guild]` multiple times, it works now. Beware that it only works on cached messages, because you are using `on_message_delete` which only works for cached messages. I suggest using `on_raw_message_delete`, for which you would have to change some parts of your code, here are the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_raw_message_delete#discord.on_raw_message_delete

Comment: `snipe_message_guilld[message.guild]` will raise KeyError if no message is deleted

Comment: That is the reason I used `try: except KeyError:` @Ceres

Comment: Ah didn't see it, got it

Answer (score 1):

Using dictionaries is the key, but [Chuaat's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67319402/12451222) answer doesn't use it correctly.

```
snipes = {}

@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    global snipes
    snipes[message.guild.id] = (message.author.id, message.content)
    await asyncio.sleep(60)
    snipes[message.guild.id] = None

@client.command()
async def snipe(self, ctx):
    if snipe.get(ctx.guild.id, None) is None:
         print('nothing to snipe')
    else:
         await ctx.send(f" author is <@{snipe[ctx.guild.id][0]}> and content is {snipe[ctx.guild.id][1]}", allowed_mentions= discord.AllowedMentions.none)
```

We use `message.guild.id` instead of `message.guild` to make the check easier.

### References:

- [Allowed_Mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=allowed_mentions#discord.AllowedMentions) is used so that we don't mention the author, you could also get their name and use it instead of mentioning.