# Snipe command in cogs discord,py

Tags: discord.py

I am reworking my discord bot with cogs and I'm stuck on the snipe function:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Snipe(commands.Cog):

  def __init__(self, client):
    self.Client = client

  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_ready(self):
   print ("Snipe is now enabled")
  async def on_message_delete(self, message):
   messageauthor = {}
   messagecontent = {}
   messageauthor[message.channel.id] = message.author
   messagecontent[message.channel.id] = message.content

  @commands.command()
  async def snipe(self, ctx):
   channel = ctx.channel
   try:
      em = discord.Embed(description = f"said:\n{ctx.messagecontent[channel.id]}", color = 0x00c230)
      em.set_author(name = f"Last deleted message in #{ctx.channel.name}")
      em.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/352793093105254402/8a2018de21ad29973696bfbf92fc31cd.png?size=4096")
      em.set_footer(text = f"Snipe requested by {ctx.message.author}")
      await ctx.channel.send(embed = em)
   except:
     embed = discord.Embed(colour = 0x00c230)
     embed.set_author(name=f"There are no deleted messages in #{ctx.channel.name}!")
     embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/352793093105254402/8a2018de21ad29973696bfbf92fc31cd.png?size=4096")
     embed.set_footer(text=f"Snipe requested by {ctx.message.author}")
     await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Snipe(client))
```

This is my code so far, this is the part that doesn't seem to work:

```
@commands.command()
  async def snipe(self, ctx):
   channel = ctx.channel
   try:
      em = discord.Embed(description = f"said:\n{ctx.messagecontent[channel.id]}", color = 0x00c230)
      em.set_author(name = f"Last deleted message in #{ctx.channel.name}")
      em.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/352793093105254402/8a2018de21ad29973696bfbf92fc31cd.png?size=4096")
      em.set_footer(text = f"Snipe requested by {ctx.message.author}")
      await ctx.channel.send(embed = em)
```

When I try to snipe a deleted message it just shows the text for the "no messages to snipe" option.
If anyone can help with this/has their own code, edit it as much as you want ill work around that,
Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318718/discord-py-snipe-command-shows-deleted-messages-from-other-guilds) help you?

Comment: No, it doesn't, I copied the code over ad worked it around and it still shows the failed snipe message.

Comment: I guess I will just put the snipe in the main bot file and not work in cogs. If anyone got an answer to this  I would also appreciate it

Comment: Be aware that discord is making message content a Privileged Intent in April of 2022. [Read about it here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410940809111). Although its only for the verified bots.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in python, if you assign a variable in a function, it will be considered as a local variable. To make it global, you will need to use the `global` keyword. but since you are coding in a class, you can assign the variable to the class, like:

```py
# to assign
self.messageauthor = {}

# to use
print(self.messageauthor)
```

So your new code will be:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def snipe(self, ctx):
   channel = ctx.channel
   try:
      em = discord.Embed(title="Put something here", description = f"said:\n{ctx.messagecontent[channel.id]}", color = '0x00c230') #color code should be a str
      em.set_author(name = f"Last deleted message in #{ctx.channel.name}")
      em.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/352793093105254402/8a2018de21ad29973696bfbf92fc31cd.png?size=4096")
      em.set_footer(text = f"Snipe requested by {ctx.message.author}")
      await ctx.channel.send(embed = em)
   except:
     embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="", colour = '0x00c230') # should be str
     embed.set_author(name=f"There are no deleted messages in #{ctx.channel.name}!")
     embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/352793093105254402/8a2018de21ad29973696bfbf92fc31cd.png?size=4096")
     embed.set_footer(text=f"Snipe requested by {ctx.message.author}")
     await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Also, `title` and `description` are required arguments to make an embed. and, the html color code should be a str. (Use ''). I hope this much helps you.